# Doing price(decimal) calculations on client side via javascript is safe?

Tags: javascript, .net, web, decimal

I have to manipulate decimal calculations. All data is already on client side and manipulation is changing by user interactions (choices). So I can surely go to server for every user choice change but it is time consuming job and extra complexity.

I started to manipulate decimal calculations on client side and I tossed globalization parsing problems. I am also afraid that decimal calculations on server side may not equal to client side processing results.

So simply it is better to calculate decimal values on server side or there is no any problem to calculate it via JavaScript just for displaying purposes?

Answer (score 1):

It's like asking if a scientific calculator is better than a normal calculator when doing addition.

Yes it's fine, but practice caution. JS has a known issue about imprecise decimals. As far as I know, people calculate in "cents" (integers), then divide it by 100 afterwards for "dollars" (floats/decimals).

Of course you should also carry out validations afterwards. It's general knowledge that one must not readily trust client-side inputs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when dealing with currency, ALWAYS work in integers. If you're working in dollars, multiply by 100 and work in cents instead. Whatever your currency, work in units of the SMALLEST possible amount.

This will eliminate any chance of rounding errors.

Only after you have the final value in pennies, then divide it by 100 (or better yet use string manipulation) to present it with utmost precision.

This will guarantee that the client and server get the same results.

Comment: On the server it's generally not required to work with integers, `decimal` is fine. Though in this specific case using integers makes it easier to keep the js and server code in sync.

Comment: Using minor unit integers is one solution but may not always be possible, e.g. applying tax or discounts nearly always introduces floats. Another strategy is to leave everything as floats and only round once at the end. The inaccuracy of javascript floats is tiny when used for currency calculations (it occurs around the 15th significant figure) and can be ignored in most cases, provided a consistent rounding algorithm is used. And all calculations must be validated on the server.